# Type conversion in open cv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to convert an uint32_t* into a format that could be accepted by a Mat object (from open cv). I do not need to display the data from the Mat, I am simply using the mat to transport and pack information.I know that opencv does not use uint32_t and as a workaround I used int. What I did is the following:

```
Mat package = Mat(width,height, CV_32SC4);
int *dst1 = package.data;
//code that works with the dst
//finally put it back in the package
package.data = dst1;
```

The above code gives me an error at the second line. (Cannot convert from 'int *' to 'uchar *')

Comment: the Mat format should be  CV_8UC4, not  CV_32SC4, and  you need a cast : `int *dst1 = (int*)package.data;` (and you don't need the last line, no need to write back a pointer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer however, I have tried that and I get a memory exception at a memory location

Comment: Perhaps you could also post the code that causes memory exception

Comment: `CV_8U` would be unsigned chars, not ints.

Comment: the issue i had came from another function(after I solved that small memory issue everything was ok) It was wired because visual studio pointed me to the function where I did my packaging not where my exception actully was. The solution of  berak was the correct one. Thank you all for youre interest!